# Crystal for HVProg

Tags: atmega, crystal

I am going to make an [HVProg](http://www.der-hammer.info/hvprog/index_en.htm).
Can I use an 8 MHz crystal rather than a 7.3728 MHz crystal?

Answer (score 2):

No, because it affects the transfer rate for the serial connection. You would have to change the source code to change the baud rate and things. [WormFood's AVR Baud Rate Calculator](http://www.wormfood.net/avrbaudcalc.php) is good for calculating this.